# Esri mapobects in Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, esri

Has anyone installed ESRI mapobjects activeX controls in Delphi 2010? I get a conflict on tTable as a component name.

Comment: I haven't, but I know that TTable is one of the standard Delphi DB access components and has been for years and years, probably since the original release.  Whose idea was it to create another component with that name?

Comment: i think we used late binding instead.  haven't done it in d2010 but i'm just saying how we've used MO ActiveX in the past.  don't know anything about the tTable you mention...that doesn't sound right but maybe something has changed since i used MO last a couple of yrs ago.

Comment: @Mason: When writing an ActiveX, the developers won't be considering the particular idiosynchracies of every potential software development tool tht might be used to access their product and the particular techniques those tools may use when importing their type library.  Why not call your component "Table" if it represents a table.  With ActiveX after all, the name generally isn't as important as the CLSID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have MapObjects LT 2.0 installed into Delphi 2007, no conflicts and there is no type called TTable in it.  You must be using a different version of MapObjects though that does have a TTable type.  I can send you my imported pas file if it would help.

Answer (score 0):

After generating the component wrappers simply search/replace or use a refactoring to rename the generated **TTable** component in the **_TLB.pas** import unit so something else that will not conflict.

Comment: Could one use the mapping Barry describes here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/531171/why-is-gentlb-renaming-symbols-appending/531784#531784?

Comment: @Ulrich: YES!  At least, it looks like you should be able to.  For some reason I had no idea that even existed!  Cool.